# How to pass class object as a variable in Java

Tags: java, scala, reflect

I have a function below which accepts a string and converts it into a JSON Object using Jackson Api in java.

```
public JobConfig fromJson(String config)  {
        JobConfig lib = null;
        try {
            lib = mapper.readValue(config, JobConfig.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lib;
    }
```

`JobConfig.class` is my JAVA Pojo for the JSON Struncture.

I call this function like below -

```
JobConfig jobConfig = utils.fromJson(config);
```

The issue is i have to write another function for another JSON so i want this to be dynamic enough so when i call this function, i can also send the `JobConfig.class` class and it should return accordingly.

In scala i would do something like this -

```scala
def fromJson[T : Manifest](s: String): T = Serialization.read[T](s)
```

Not sure how to do this in Java. Open to new learning.

Comment: Do you mean something like `<T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> type)` which then could be called like `JobConfig config = utils.fromJson(config, JobConfig.class)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in java you can use generics as well.

your code would be like:

```
public class Main<T> {
    public T fromJson(String config)  {
        T lib = null;
        try {
            lib = mapper.readValue(config, Class<T>);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lib;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using Java generics:

```
  public <T> T fromJson(String config, Class<T> clazz) {
    T lib = null;
    try {
      lib = mapper.readValue(config, clazz);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lib;
  }
```

Call:

```
JobConfig config = fromJson("json here", JobConfig.class)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked also, i learned about Java generics

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Java Generic](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm) just like Scala Generics. It allows you with a single method declaration, a set of related methods.

> public  T fromJson(String config, Class clazz)

And then you can call this function where your 2rd parameter would be `.Class` Object